# Include WindowsBase.dll in self contained .NET Core app with trimming turned on

Tags: c#, .net

I have a console application which is targeting .NET 7.0 and I'm trying to publish the app as self contained. Inside my app, I have an Assembly Resolver which tries to load the `WindowsBase.dll`.

However, whenever I publish my app in this self contained mode, the `WindowsBase.dll` is never copied over into my dist directory (and my app fails when it is run). I'm a little out of my depth as to why this happening and haven't been able to find a solution.

For reference, my `.csproj` file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AssemblyName>MyProjectName</AssemblyName>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'">
    <OutputPath>..\bin\Debug\$(AssemblyName)</OutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <OutputPath>..\bin\Release\$(AssemblyName)</OutputPath>
    <PublishDir>..\dist\$(AssemblyName)</PublishDir>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Carter" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.2-dev-02044" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Expressions" Version="3.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Caching" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And my publish command looks like this:

```
dotnet publish PathToMyProjectSolution --configuration Release 
       --runtime win-x64 -p:PublishTrimmed=true --self-contained true
```

Comment: Why do you need `WindowsBase` in a console app?